# AWS Glue / Hive struct with undetermined struct

Tags: hive, aws-glue

Adding data to a AWS Glue table where one of the columns is a `struct` where one of the values has undetermined form.

More specifically there's a known key called `'name'`, that is a string and another called `'metadata'` that can be a dict with any structure.

Ex:

```
# Row 1
{
  "name": "Jane",
  "metadata": {
    "foo": 123,
    "bar": "something"
  }
}

# Row 2
{
  "name": "Bill",
  "metadata": {
    "baz": "something else"
  }
}
```

Note how `metadata` is a different dictionary in the two entries.

How can this be specified as a `struct`?

```
struct<
  name:string,
  metadata:?
>
```

Comment: One thing I could do is serialize `metadata` as a JSON string and have `metadata:string` in the column definition, but wondering if there's a smarter solution that will make querying for this column easier.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing what I mentioned in the comment, which is to make the column a `string` and have the JSON blob serialized to string.

SQL queries will then need to deserialize the JSON blob, which is supported in several different implementations, including AWS Athena (the one I'm using).